# Can I disable Safari's pinch-to-zoom tab switcher?

Tags: macos, safari, pdf, multi-touch

When looking at a PDF document I often want to zoom-out to scroll quickly to its contents and get an overview.

However, when I zoom-out past a certain threshold (it seems to differ per PDF) Safari thinks I want to see the tab overview:

[image]

I have never found a use for this function, so it only causes annoyance.

Can I turn this tab overview off somehow? A solution that uncouples the pinch-to-zoom gesture from the functionality would also work.

I'm on Mountain Lion 10.8.5 with Safari 6.1.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is currently not possible. Apple does not provide a way to turn this off.

Note that if your swiping is begun whilst still zoomed slightly, the tab switcher is not invoked. See this animation:

[image]

<sup>This is a pretty large GIF — it'll take a while to load and be smooth.</sup>