# How do I disable Safari's Show All Tabs gesture?

Tags: safari

Safari's Show All Tabs view is pretty useless, it only shows one tab at a time and is fairly easy to trigger with an accidental pinch gesture. How do I turn it off (as least for the pinch gesture)?

Comment: related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127673/can-i-disable-safaris-pinch-to-zoom-tab-switcher

Comment: Safari 8's tab manager is quite nice, and quite useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is currently not possible. Apple does not provide a way to turn off this gesture.

Note that if you pinch out whilst still zoomed in slightly, the tab switcher is not invoked.

[image]

Comment: I recall my Safari doing this, but it doesn't happen anymore. When I pinch to zoom out ever-so-slightly, Tab Overview appears immediately. I've also noticed that, sometimes, nothing happens on the first pinch (in or out). Ideas, anyone?

Comment: you can change binary https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-to-disable-Safaris-Show-All-Tabs-feature/answer/Mike-McFadden maybe this works now :D

Answer (score 8):

You can easily disable this by installing [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net), and then for **Safari** adding a new Touchpad gesture for **Pinch Out** with no action.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Settings for BetterTouchTool to disable Safari pinch gesture]

Comment: But then could you still zoom in and out of a web[age - or just zoom in?

Comment: You would presumably have to zoom in slightly and then zoom out, in order to zoom out. Not the nicest solution

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can disable it by going to System Settings → Trackpad → Scroll & Zoom and then uncheck the Zoom in or out box. Of course, by doing this, you also won't be able to pinch to zoom in and out on webpages and in other apps.

Comment: Disabling pinch zoom systemwide is a blunt hack. Not a criticism of the answer, but of Apple's UI/UX decision making.